# How to prevent NoSuchElementException using Optional class in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type, nosuchelementexception

While filtering through a list of user defined class type using Stream API has been encountered some cases where no element has been found in the *list* for given condition.

How to prevent exception in such case and handle according to business logic using optional class?

Stream API method looks like :

```
public static Optional<Policy> getPolicy(ReturnTermPolicy policyType, 
                                         String policyKey) {
    
    Optional<Policy> policy = Optional.of(policyType.getPolicies().stream()
        .filter(temp -> temp.getPolicyKey().equals(policyKey))
        .findFirst().get());
    
    return policy;
}
```

The calling code looks like that:

```
Optional<Policy> updatedPolicyOptional = getPolicy(updatedPolies,policykey); // <- exception is being generated here

if (updatedPolicyOptional.isPresent()) {
    // business logic
}
else {
    // business logic
}
```

*Output :*

```
Verify audit report for update made in TC_08
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to extract the result from the optional object just in order to wrap it with an optional again.

It's pointless and will trigger `NoSuchElementException` if result is not present. To solve the problem, remove the call of `get()` which both unsafe and redundant in this case:

```
public static Optional<Policy> getPolicy(ReturnTermPolicy policyType, 
                                         String policyKey) {
    
    return policyType.getPolicies().stream()
        .filter(temp -> temp.getPolicyKey().equals(policyKey))
        .findFirst();
}
```

In order implement your conditional logic fluently you can make use of [`Optional.ifPresentOrElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)) which expects a `Consumer` that would be executed if result is present and a `Runnable` that will be fired in case if optional is empty. Note, this method is accessible with Java 9.

```
getPolicy(updatedPolies,policykey).ifPresentOrElse(policy -> doSomething(policy), 
            () -> doSomethingElse());
```

With Java 8 you can use [`Optional.ifPresentOrElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent()) that expects consumer and can cave the `if` part of conditional logic. And for the case of empty optional, you will need a condition.

```
Optional<Policy> policy = getPolicy(updatedPolies,policykey);
    
policy.ifPresentOrElse(policy -> doSomething(policy));
        
if (!policy.isPresent()) doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 1):

`findFirst()` already returns an `Optional`, trying to `get()` it leads to an error when it is  empty. So your function should be:

```
public static Optional<Policy> getPolicy(ReturnTermPolicy policyType, 
                                         String policyKey) {    
    return = policyType.getPolicies().stream()
        .filter(temp -> temp.getPolicyKey().equals(policyKey))
        .findFirst();        
}
```

And depending on your Java version (**and** your business logic) you can use things like:

**Java 8.**

```
if (updatedPolicyOptional.isPresent()) {
    // business logic
}
else {
    // business logic
}
```

or

```
T value = updatedPolicyOptional(mapToTFunctor).orElse(someTValue);
```

**Java 9.**

```
updatedPolicyOptional.ifPresentOrElse(someConsumer,someNoParamFunctor);
```